# Correctly setting variables from JSON data retrieved via an AJAX call in jQuery/jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have a single file, multi page jQueyMobile application which makes several requests to a service for data. The data comes back in JSON. Some requests happen on the front page of the app, but others happen dynamically as the user proceeds through the app.

In several pages I call data with a main function to retrieve the data and then success and error functions to handle receipt (or not) of data. e.g.

```
function getStuff(thisKey) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dataURL,
        cache: false, 
        data: {docid:thisKey},
        success: getStuffSuccess,
        error: getStuffError,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: showSpinner,
        complete: hideSpinner               
    });

}

function getStuffSuccess(data, status){
// do stuff on success
}

function getStuffError(data, status){
// do stuff on success
}
```

This approach has worked throughout the application. However I seem to have hit a limit with this version of the above approach

```
function getDocumentData(thisKey) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: documentDataURL,
        cache: false, 
        data: {docid:thisKey},
        success: onDocumentDataSuccess,
        error: onDocumentDataError,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: showSpinner,
        complete: hideSpinner               
    });

}

function onDocumentDataSuccess(data, status){

    // trim data
    data            = $.trim(data);
    console.log(data);

    // parse data
    var resultData  = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(resultData);

    // set var data
    var document_id             = resultData.ID;
    console.log(document_id);
}

function onDocumentDataError(data, status){
// blah
}
```

There is valid data in both the first two console.log. When I set document_id it comes back as undefined in the console.

As I said earlier, this is happening despite other calls that work in the same way operating correctly.

I have read other posts on here and experimented with various things switching the async attribute of the call between true and false in case there is some timing problem between data being returned in the console. Also I've been through the rest of the code to make sure I'm not sharing any variable names - whatever I try I can't make it work.

Am I hitting some sort of limit with the number of these requests I can make in a jQueryMobile app? Is this the correct way to be even making these requests?

Thanks for reading - any advice is greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Dom

---

The console.log returns the following:

After the HTTP POST

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/businessguardnet/app/index.cfm?     method=document". jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
send jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
b.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
getDocData business-shield.js:305
createDocumentPageView business-shield.js:365
(anonymous function) VM230:1
```

After the Trim data

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","DOCTITLE","DOCPRECIS","DOCFILENAME","DOCFILESIZE","DATEADDED"],"DATA":[[156,"Electricity - Kitchen","<html \/>","electricity_kitchen.doc",108544,"July, 16 2010 13:37:22"]]} business-shield.js:323
```

After the Parse data

```
Object {COLUMNS: Array[6], DATA: Array[1]}
COLUMNS: Array[6]
0: "ID"
1: "DOCTITLE"
2: "DOCPRECIS"
3: "DOCFILENAME"
4: "DOCFILESIZE"
5: "DATEADDED"
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
DATA: Array[1]
0: Array[6]
0: 156
1: "Electricity - Kitchen"
2: "<html />"
3: "electricity_kitchen.doc"
4: 108544
5: "July, 16 2010 13:37:22"
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
business-shield.js:327
```

At the set variable (in this case this is console.log(resultData.ID) but I get the same if I do console.log(document_id))

```
undefined
```

Comment: Have you checked on the browser developer tools to see what you get in the HTTP response?

Comment: What happens if you do a console.log(resultData.ID)? Is that also undefined?

Comment: please check resultData it contains ID or not? or it will be better if you will share the response which you have seen in console.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help - I've updated the console.log above

Answer (score 0):

I think this was down to the way the data was being returned by the service. I found that if I did the following

```
data               = $.trim(data);
var resultData     = JSON.parse(data);
var document_data  = resultData.DATA[0];
var document_id    = document_data[0];
```

Then document_id would return a value

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Cheers
Dom